# How to get the values from object Proxy and Pass to local Variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, proxy

I  need get a list of devices (video and Input/output audio) using a navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().
First, i create one function that returns the result to another page however using a console.log(result) i get one proxy object.
How to get this result and Pass to local Variable?

[image]

Comment: The proxy is probably created by Vue. Doesn't mean that you can't pass it around and access it though.

Comment: Treat the proxy as if it were the array itself. All array operations are still accessible through the proxy. e.g., `proxyArr[0]` accesses the first array element. `proxyArr.filter(item => item.deviceId === 'default')` gets all array items with a `deviceId` equal to `"default"`.

Answer (score 2):

proxies are either created by vue or asynchronous job, in your problem you don't need to do anything your array is accessible like a normal array you can assign result value to any variable you want and it works just fine.